# How to redirect print result from python shell into qtextedit pyqt?

Tags: qtextedit

I want my output to appear in my pyqt textedit not python shell after clicking a pushbutton. I am not familiar with subprocess or stdout stuff and not even sure if this will involve them. Need some help here. Here is part of my code:

```py
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Dialog)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 200, 431, 241))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))

def readI2C(self):
    data = i2c.read_byte(0x50)
    return data
    self.textEdit.setText(data)
```

This code does not print anything. I tried it with `print data` but this prints result in python shell. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this line `self.textEdit.setText(data)` before `return data`. Once you return value from method, lines after return will not execute.

Also, if you're going to use textEdit only for output (not for editing) set self.textEdit.setReadOnly(1)

Comment: I put `self.textEdit.setText(data)` and `self.textEdit.setReadOnly(1)` before `return data` but now I received an error: `TypeError: QTextEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'`

Comment: it means `data` is integer type and method `setText` needs QString type.
fix it to be `self.textEdit.setText(str(data))`